# NextJS - Appending a query param to a dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my NextJS app, I have a language selector that's visible on every page. When I select a new language, I just want to replace the current URL by appending a query param `lang=en` to it.

Here's the function that replaces the URL:

```
const changeLanguage = (lang: LanguageID) => {
    replace({
      pathname,
      query: { ...query, lang },
    });
  };
```

In this example, `replace`, `query` and `pathname` are coming from the next router.

Now, everything works for static routes, but I'm unable to make it work for dynamic routes. For example, I have the following folder structure:

```
pages
|_customers
|__index.tsx
|__[customerId].tsx
```

If I'm on `http://localhost/customers` and I change my language to English, the URL changes to `http://localhost/customers?lang=en` which is what I want. However, if I'm on `http://localhost/customer/1` and I change my language to English, the URL changes to `http://localhost/customers/[customerId]?customerId=1&lang=en`, instead of the URL I'm expecting `http://localhost/customers/1?lang=en`.

Now, I know that I could use `asPath` on the router, and reconstruct the query string object by appending `lang` to it, but I feel that it's something that should be build into Next. Also, I know it could be easily done with vanilla JS, but it's not the point here.

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to append query params to a dynamic route without doing a server-side re-rendering?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using next.js route api, use window.location.

Comment: Question in `changeLanguage = (lang: LanguageID)`  are you trying to set a default value? Or is this TypeScript syntax?

Comment: @JoseFelix like I said in my post, I know it can easily be done in vanilla JS, but I want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I think the easiest way here is to give the `pathname` property the `asPath` value from the router.

Comment: @JoseFelix the problem with that solution is that it causes a server-side re-rendering, which I want to avoid if possible. That's why I asked the question, but I'm starting to feel like it's not really possible with Next...

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisGagnon did you consider adding the shallow option to avoid a serverside re-render? along these lines
``replace({ query: { ...query, lang }, undefined, { shallow: true } });``

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Just add more param to current router then push itself

```
const router = useRouter();
router.query.NEWPARAMS = "VALUE"
router.push(router)
```

Comment: Just take caution if you use **rewrites**, because this approach won't work. This will change the browser url to the path the rewrite **points to** inside the `pages` folder, instead of using the correct url. Seems like a nextjs bug to me.

Comment: I think this approach is outdated

Comment: This won't work properly if **server.js** is used for rendering pages where actual path and rendered path may not be same.

Comment: Definitely causes problems - including `Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format` errors.

Comment: Even though there may be some contextual issues with this approach, the logic above at least worked for the context I needed and also works with `router.replace` (probably with the same caveats as `router.push`).

Answer (score 31):

The solution which doesn't need to send the whole previous route, as `replace` just replaces what we need to replace, so query params:

```js
const router = useRouter();
router.replace({
   query: { ...router.query, key: value },
});
```

Comment: It doesn't only replace query params, but: `replace will prevent adding a new URL entry into the history stack.`

Comment: This solved it for me! Using the selected answer gave me a `Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format` error

Answer (score 16):

If we want to have this as a link - use it like so:

```
// ...
const { query } = useRouter();
// ...

<Link
    href={{
        pathname: router.pathname,
        query: { ...query, lang },
    }}
    passHref
    shallow
    replace
></Link>
```

Comment: Worked for me best :)

Comment: This works but encode special chars from my current url, eg switch from https://localhost/maps/@55.64817,-20.98599,13z to encoded "@" & ","

Answer (score 9):

I tried adding my param to the route query and pushing the router itself, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66382571/9424618), it works, but I got a lot of warnings:
[image]

So, I then pushed to `/` and passed my query params as following:

```js
const router = useRouter();
router.push({ href: '/', query: { myQueryParam: value  } });
```

I hope that works for you too.

Comment: This works for me with Next.JS 13.  To update a single param when you have multiple, spread the current params into the `push` invocation: `router.push({ href: "./", query: { ...router.query, myQueryParam: value } })`

Answer (score 9):

An alternative approach when you have dynamic routing in Next.js, and want to do a shallow adjustment of the route to reflect updated query params, is to try:

```
const router = useRouter()
const url = {
      pathname: router.pathname,
      query: { ...router.query, page: 2 }
    }
router.push(url, undefined, { shallow: true })
```

This will retreive the current path (`router.pathname`) and query (`router.query`) details, and merge them in along with your new `page` query param. If your forget to merge in the existing query params you might see an error like:

> The provided href value is missing query values to be interpolated
> properly

Comment: Now in next 13 you'll get pathname/query does not exist on type AppRouterInstance. 

It is because the 'query' object has been removed from useRouter hook. So right now, you have to use 'useSearchParams()'. 

Check out new documentation - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the solution that I wanted to avoid in the first place, which was to play with the `asPath` value. Atleast, there's no server-side re-rendering being done since the path is the same.

Here's my updated `changeLanguage` function (`stringifyUrl` is coming from the `query-string` package)

```
  const changeLanguage = (lang: LanguageID) => {
    const newPathname = stringifyUrl({ url: pathname, query: { ...query, lang } });
    const newAsPath = stringifyUrl({ url: asPath, query: { lang } });
    replace(newPathname, newAsPath);
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still looking the answer ,for Next,js ^11.1.2.I hope this helps you out.Use

```
const router = useRouter();
router.push({ pathname: "/search", query: { key: key } });
```

Comment: this way I'll need to manually remount the path

Answer (score 2):

In latest version, **Next 13**, some of the functionality moved to other hooks, which query and path are some of them. You can use `useSearchParams` to get query and `usePathname` instead of pathname. By the time I am writing this answer, it does not have a stable version and you can find the beta documents here:
https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-router

Answer (score 1):

If you are using App Router, The `query` object has been removed and is replaced by `useSearchParams()`, you need to [update `searchParams`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#updating-searchparams):

```js
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  // Get a new searchParams string by merging the current
  // searchParams with a provided key/value pair
  const createQueryString = useCallback(
    (name: string, value: string) => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString())
      params.set(name, value)
 
      return params.toString()
    },
    [searchParams]
  )
 
  return (
    <>
      {/* using useRouter */}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // <pathname>?sort=asc
          router.push(pathname + '?' + createQueryString('sort', 'asc'))
        }}
      >
        ASC
      </button>
 
      {/* using <Link> */}
      <Link
        href={
          // <pathname>?sort=desc
          pathname + '?' + createQueryString('sort', 'desc')
        }
      >
        DESC
      </Link>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with is that doesn't cause the `Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format` is to do this pattern  `router.query.plan = plan.title; router.push({ query: router.query });`

Answer (score 0):

for nextjs 13 I just found this,

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
router.push(`?page=${page}`)
```

you just need to handle every query you want

Answer (score -1):

```
  let queryParams;
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {  
    // The search property returns the querystring part of a URL, including the question mark (?).
    queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    // quaeryParams object has nice methods
    // console.log("window.location.search", queryParams);
    // console.log("query get", queryParams.get("location"));
  }
```

inside `changeLanguage`,

```
const changeLanguage = (lang: LanguageID) => {
    if (queryParams.has("lang")) {
      queryParams.set("lang", lang);
    } else {
      // otherwise append
      queryParams.append("lang", lang);
    }
    router.replace({
      search: queryParams.toString(),
    });
  };
```