# Add query string to ALL links in application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Here is the situation... I have a Next.js app that has been up for a bit, we have a ton of code already writen.

Recently we started running some ads and we need to understand how they are doing...

Someone could land on our site with either of the two URLs.

```
www.site.com/page // user came to our site NOT from ad
www.site.com/page?ad=campaign1 // user came from one of our ads.
```

If a user comes to our site with the "ad" querystring, I would like to append that to ALL links on our site.

How would I go about doing that in react/nextjs?  we have a ton of components already built and even some blog posts where we are just rendoring raw HTML.

Without going and editing a zillion components.  How would I go about appending the query string to all links?

Thanks

Comment: this might be solution to your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61470662/4481312

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom `Link` component, as a wrapper to `next/link`, that would check for the query string and add it to the `href` of the Next.js `Link`.

```js
// components/link.jsx

import NextLink from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Link = ({ children, href }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [, queryString] = router.asPath.split('?');
  const hrefWithQuery = `${href}${queryString ? `?${queryString}` : ''}`;
  return <NextLink href={hrefWithQuery}>{children}</NextLink>;
};

export default Link;
```

Then replace all imports of `next/link` with the path to the new component wherever they are used (a simple search & replace would do).

Comment: There are some components (like the body of a blog post) that just have raw "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" content.  How would you handle that?

Comment: Before setting it to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you could parse the raw HTML, look for links and modify their `href`s with the same logic as above. Can't think of a solution that doesn't involve parsing the HTML.